# How to change the path that comes with the output of which command?

Tags: linux, path, which

When I `which mex` at the linux system it gives a path but I want to change this path to another one. How can I set this default path to another location ?

Comment: If `which mex` returns a certain path this means that the `mex` executable is actually placed in there. If you want the executable to be somewhere else you have to move it. Please explain what exactly you need to do, and give a specific example.

Comment: ...but as soon as there are multiple `mex` in the search path, the problem is not that trivial ([nice example](http://superuser.com/q/346403/173159))

Answer (score 5):

On a certain system I get this output:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

This means that upon executing the command

```
$ foo
```

the shell will look for *executable* files in this order:

1. `/usr/local/bin/foo`
2. `/usr/bin/foo`
3. `/bin/foo`
4. `/usr/local/games/foo`
5. `/usr/games/foo`

and run the first one encountered.

`which foo` would return the path of the first of these matches, or nothing if an executable file named `foo` does not exist in the `PATH` directories (note the `which -a` switch which will return *all* matches in order, not just the first one).

You could e.g. reorder the directories in the `PATH` variable to change the lookup order, but that is probably not the solution to your "real" question. If you have an executable file in a higher priority directory "shadowing" the wanted one, you could either move the first one away, or simply execute the lower priority one with its full path.

---

I recognize `mex` as part of the Matlab installation. Trying to guess what you want to do, perhaps you could temporarily modify the `PATH` for a single running process as such:

```
$ PATH=/home/user/myownexecs:$PATH matlab
```

where `/home/user/myownexecs/mex` is the `mex` executable you want to give precedence. This will temporarily modify the `PATH` variable for the `matlab` process, but not interfere with the system in general in a lasting way.

You should clarify your question to [ask what you *really* want to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to get more fitting answers, though.